# `pyparsing`: iterating over `ParsedResults`

Tags: python, pyparsing

I've just started using `pyparsing` this evening and I've built a complex grammar which describes some sources I'm working with very effectively.  It was very easy and very powerful.  However, I'm having some trouble working with `ParsedResults`.  I need to be able to iterate over nested tokens in the order that they're found, and I'm finding it a little frustrating.  I've abstracted my problem to a simple case:

```
import pyparsing as pp

word = pp.Word(pp.alphas + ',.')('word*')
direct_speech = pp.Suppress('“') + pp.Group(pp.OneOrMore(word))('direct_speech*') + pp.Suppress('”')
sentence = pp.Group(pp.OneOrMore(word | direct_speech))('sentence')

test_string = 'Lorem ipsum “dolor sit” amet, consectetur.'

r = sentence.parseString(test_string)

print r.asXML('div')

print ''

for name, item in r.sentence.items():
    print name, item

print ''

for item in r.sentence:
    print item.getName(), item.asList()
```

as far as I can see, this ought to work?  Here is the output:

```
<div>
  <sentence>
    <word>Lorem</word>
    <word>ipsum</word>
    <direct_speech>
      <word>dolor</word>
      <word>sit</word>
    </direct_speech>
    <word>amet,</word>
    <word>consectetur.</word>
  </sentence>
</div>

word ['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'amet,', 'consectetur.']
direct_speech [['dolor', 'sit']]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 27, in <module>
    print item.getName(), item.asList()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getName'
```

The XML output seems to indicate that the string is parsed exactly as I would wish, but I can't iterate over the sentence, for example, to reconstruct it.

Is there a way to do what I need to?

Thanks!

**edit:**

I've been using this:

```
for item in r.sentence:
    if isinstance(item, basestring):
        print item
    else:
        print item.getName(), item
```

but it doesn't help me all that much, because I can't distinguish different types of string.  Here is a slightly expanded example:

```
word = pp.Word(pp.alphas + ',.')('word*')
number = pp.Word(pp.nums + ',.')('number*')

direct_speech = pp.Suppress('“') + pp.Group(pp.OneOrMore(word | number))('direct_speech*') + pp.Suppress('”')
sentence = pp.Group(pp.OneOrMore(word | number | direct_speech))('sentence')

test_string = 'Lorem 14 ipsum “dolor 22 sit” amet, consectetur.'

r = sentence.parseString(test_string)

for i, item in enumerate(r.sentence):
    if isinstance(item, basestring):
        print i, item
    else:
        print i, item.getName(), item
```

the output is:

```
0 Lorem
1 14
2 ipsum
3 word ['dolor', '22', 'sit']
4 amet,
5 consectetur.
```

not too helpful.  I can't distinguish between `word` and `number`, and the `direct_speech` element is labelled `word`?!

I'm obviously missing something.  All I want to do is:

```
for item in r.sentence:
    if (item is a number):
        do something
    elif (item is a word):
        do something else
etc. ...
```

should I be approaching this differently?

Comment: Pity, but pyparsing still does not seem to return types of tokens in ParseResults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, I've tried a number of different approaches now and I can't get what I need, so (absurd though it seems), I'm using `.asXML()` and parsing the resulting XML.  Here's my example:

```
import pyparsing as pp

word = pp.Word(pp.alphas + ',.')('word*')
number = pp.Word(pp.nums + ',.')('number*')
direct_speech = pp.Suppress('“') + pp.Group(pp.OneOrMore(word | number))('direct_speech*') + pp.Suppress('”')
sentence = pp.Group(pp.OneOrMore(word | number | direct_speech))('sentence')

test_string = 'Lorem 14 ipsum “dolor 22 sit” amet, consectetur.'
r = sentence.parseString(test_string)

from lxml import etree
xml = etree.fromstring(r.sentence.asXML('sentence'))
for el in xml:
    if len(el):
        print el.tag
        for sub_el in el:
            print '  ', sub_el.tag, ':', sub_el.text
    else:
        print el.tag, ':',  el.text
```

which outputs:

```
word : Lorem
number : 14
word : ipsum
direct_speech
   word : dolor
   number : 22
   word : sit
word : amet,
word : consectetur.
```

seems like a long way around the houses, but there doesn't seem to be a better way.

Answer (score 5):

`r.sentence` contains a mix of strings and ParseResults, and only ParseResults support `getName()`. Have you tried just iterating over `r.sentence`? If I print it out using asList(), I get:

```
['Lorem', 'ipsum', ['dolor', 'sit'], 'amet,', 'consectetur.']
```

Or this snippet:

```
for item in r.sentence:
    print type(item),item.asList() if isinstance(item,pp.ParseResults) else item
```

Gives:

```
<type 'str'> Lorem
<type 'str'> ipsum
<class 'pyparsing.ParseResults'> ['dolor', 'sit']
<type 'str'> amet,
<type 'str'> consectetur.
```

I'm not sure I answered your question, but does that shed any light on where to go next?

(Welcome to Pyparsing)